# After bringing up openbox, "aplay -l" requires sudo. Help

Tags: sound, alsa

Folks,

I have built a minimal Ubuntu server 14.04 + openbox.

After I login, and before I run startx, aplay -l displays all devices. However, once I run startx, aplay -l does not work:

```
$ aplay -l

displays all devices

$ startx

Now open a terminal window
$ aplay -l

null
  Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
```

Wondering what do I need to do to fix this problem.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Finally fixed the problem.

It appears openbox removes user acl from /dev/snd/*.

Before I start openbox, if I run the following command, I see my username with "rw" permissions.

```
$ sudo getfacl /dev/snd/*
```

However, if I run the same command from openbox terminal, my username is not listed at all.

Fortunately, group "audio" is listed in both cases with "rw" permissions.

You just add your username to "audio" group and restart openbox. You are good to go.

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G audio peter
```

Hope you find this useful.

Regards,
Peter